# Get data from URL in php contains error

Tags: php, facebook, url, file-get-contents

I am trying to get the data from `URL`. It contains Facebook user's friend list. I have to `pass fbid and access-token`. it'll `return friend list`.

Here is url:

```
<?php
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/friends?access_token=$fb_accesstoken";
?>
```

But this `URL` contains error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 190,
      "error_subcode": 460,
      "fbtrace_id": "BSpC5i0A6Oo"
   }
}
```

So i put condition like this:

```
<?php
if(!strpos($url, 'error')) {
   $data = file_get_contents($url);
   // further process.
} else {
   $data = array();
}
?>
```

I can understand the error given, but i have also put the condition for that and still it gives me same.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: It is not the URL that is “containing the error”, it is the _response_ that you get when requesting that URL. Checking the URL for whether it contains the text `error` therefor makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

You should use json_decode function.

```php
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/friends?access_token=$fb_accesstoken";

$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);

if(!isset($response['error'])) {
     // further process.
     // Do whatever 
} else {
     $data = array();
}
```

Comment: `$data` is just string. so i used `strpos`

Comment: Flow shoud be : build URL > call > get data > parse > do whatever based on response.

Comment: but it is stopped from this url

Comment: You need to check error in your response when you call URL. In your code checking for error in `$url` variable.

Comment: but when i call url, that time it is stopped and giving me error

Comment: giving me error in this code: `$res = file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: `file_get_contents` and `curl` are used for same purpose. You can get remote URL contents via both function. Most of people use curl.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data via CURL as

```
 <?php
        $curlSession = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/$fbid/friends?access_token=$fb_accesstoken');
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
        curl_close($curlSession);
    ?>
```

if you just want the raw JSON data, then simply remove the json_decode

Comment: from url i am getting string data.

Comment: then whats the problem

Comment: strpos is not checkng

Comment: if(strpos($url, 'error') !== false) {
    // do something here
}  check this